# Mongodb query on a field depending on another field

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in mongodb. Here is the link https://mongoplayground.net/p/aDMwOc5Wal4.
I need all the Dogs, Oranges and Red colored vegetables.

I am trying a query but not getting the approach.

Comment: your query seems to be correct, but the problem is that there is no document to match that query,  try this documents: https://mongoplayground.net/p/zF25OScE-Q2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this.

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      "type": {
        "$in": [
          "Dog",
          "Orange"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      $and: [
        {
          "color": {
            "$in": [
              "red"
            ]
          },
          "cat": {
            "$in": [
              "Vegetable"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```